# decode gzip using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gzip

hey guys i want to parse a restful xml web service which is gzipped using jquery or javascript . can anyone help on the same

Comment: If the web service is implemented correctly and you're querying it via XHR (e.g., jQuery's `ajax` or related functions), the browser should unzip it for you before you see it; the fact it's gzipped should be completely transparent to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an AJAX post to get this data, I suggest using the server-side language to do it. I think this is the only way for it to actually work (AJAX post to a server-side language)